# Initializing time intensive subsystem in Websocket application

Tags: java, netbeans, websocket

I am creating a websocket application, and I want to perform a one-time time intensive task at program initialization. In creating this application, the recommended practice (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-websocketapi.html) is to override the following functions:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/testendpoint", encoders = {TestEncoder.class}, decoders = {TestDecoder.class})
public class WSEndpoint 
{   
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session wsSession, CommandIn command) throws IOException, EncodeException 
    {
        ...
    } 

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session wsSession) 
    {
        ...
    }    

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session wsSession) 
    {
        ...
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) 
    {
    }    
}
```

So when a new connection/session is created, "onOpen" would be called and when a new message is received, "onMessage" is called.

What I want to do is, before letting the user create sessions and send commands (via browser front end), to initialize the subsystem that takes about 20 seconds to initialize. If it's initialized only at "first requested use", as I am doing now, then the user experience gets interrupted. Clearly, there is no "main" function visible here (presumably, called by the websocket framework at a deeper level).

What do you guys recommend I do to achieve what I want to do? Currently, I have the initialization code in a static block in an internal class - which only gets executed once - but gets executed when the class is first "called/used", interrupting the user experience.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best place for initialization code in a web application is inside a [`ServletContextListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)'s [`contextInitialized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method.

This way you do your initialization when the application starts.